# Adding a specific line after finding a pariticular line

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I have a huge codebase containing 400-500 files. In most of the files we have these kind of lines: `<cfcatch type="any"> / <cfcatch type="database"> / <cfcatch>` etc. So the common pattern is `<cfcatch` .

Wherever there is a `<cfcatch`, I need to add this new line after that line, i.e. `<cfinclude template="test.cfm">`.

So `<cfcatch type="any">`
will now be:

`<cfcatch type="any"> <cfinclude template="test.cfm">`

I tried with multiple regex replaces, but no success.

Comment: Please provide clear "before" and "after" examples. Including a couple of lines either side would be good.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in 3 steps:

#### Step 1:

Using *Find in Files* determine a string which is NOT contained in any files, i.e. there are together 0 occurrences in all 500 files. Let's say you found that it is string `***###***`. (I'm avoiding letters to steer clear of case sensitivity, making the solution simpler.)

#### Step 2:

Using *Find in Files*:

- Find: `(^\<cfcatch.*$)`
- Replace with: `\1***###***`
- Search mode:

  - Regular expression
  - ". matches newliine" option: unchecked

Search and replace in all files.

#### Step 3:

Using *Find in Files*:

- Find: `***###***`
- Replace with: `\r\n<cfinclude template="test.cfm">`
- Search mode: Extended

Search and replace in all files.

#### Done :)

Answer (score 0):

With the following assumptions:

- you have no `<cfcatch></cfcatch>` tags in one line (`<cfinclude...` will still be insered below!)
- you have no `<cfcatch/>` (`<cfinclude...` will still be insered below!)
- you do not care about indentation of the inserted `<cfinclude...`

...the solution is:

- Find: `(<cfcatch.*)$(\s)`
- Replace with: `\1\2<cfinclude template="test.cfm">`

If these assumptions are incorrect, let me know in a comment and I shall correct my solution to match these requirements.